# simple design problem : parent, child ; teacher,student

Tags: oop, class-design

very simple problem, but i want to see how experts look at it.

This is just imaginary software just to understand OOP.
I have a school administration software. So I have classes

- Student
- ClassRoom
- Teacher

Now I assign a teacher as class-teacher for a particular classroom. Thus
ClassRoom contains

```
Teacher classTeacher; 
Student[] students;
```

Now the complete program is written and everything works fine ...

#### Problem:

Now what If the principal puts a new rule, that there should not exist a student to whom the Teacher is the Parent.
Now we need to bring more parameters and lot of changes in our code for a small requirement.
How should the design be in order for future changes in requirements (which will inevitably come) to only require minor changes in the code?

Comment: That's not a "small" requirement. Your code wasn't designed to keep track of a student's parents, or a teacher's children. You're going to have to add properties that track and store that information in order for this to work, which is going to require a lot of changes in the code anyway. Don't solve problems before they exist.

Comment: What's with the `String` before each of your `ClassRoom` attributes?

Comment: ok. I was re-reading java from scratch and got this doubt. 
It was just a wild thought. 
Thanks

Comment: Steve 
Thats the blunder of the decade . Sorry !!!

Comment: The last sentence makes it sound like you want to avoid any changes at all (thus not satisfying the requirements) - a better way of formulating the question might perhaps be "How should the design be in order for future changes in _requirements_ (which will inevitably come) to only require minor changes in the _code_?". There is no single answer to that, since you cannot know which requirements the future will bring, but there are many design principles that might help, such as the principle of [low coupling and high cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-Coupling_/_High-Cohesion_pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be a big code change, this should be a validation change.

**Psuedo-Code:**

```
Class ClassRoom {
    List<Student> students
    Teacher teacher

    ClassRoom(Teacher _teacher, List<Student> students) {
        teacher = _teacher;
        SetStudents(students);
    }

    void SetStudents(List<Student> _students) {
         foreach (Student s in _students) {
             if (validate(s)) {
                 students.add(s);
             } else {
                 // error handling logic
             }
         }
    }

    void validate(Student student) {
        if (student.parent == teacher) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

class Student : Person {
    Person parent
}

class Teacher : Person { }
```

Sure you are going to have to go into the database and the codebase and add "Parent" properties to all your students. But that also shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Looks awesome ! :) 
But I didnt understand the comparison step. 
What type is student.Parent .... It cant be a string , and teacher cant be a string either . 
SO the logic involves comparing two objects of different types. 
So we need to have a property thats unique universally ... like the citizenship id or something like that to figure out that the parent object and teacher object is same. 

I like your answer !

Comment: @Skeptor I've added the class definitions for Teacher & Student. `parent` is just a public field inside `Student`. in this case I would add a `Person` base class so that you can compare the teacher to a parent.